# Audit for OneToOne attributes

Tags: eclipselink

Using Glassfish 3.1.2 and eclipselink 2.2.0.
I have to track changes for following entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({AuditListener.class})
@Customizer(AuditListener.class)
public class Client extends Person {
...
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private ConsumptionRoomAndPost consumptionRoomAndPost;
...
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<Document> documentList;
...
```

**AuditListener:**

```
public class AuditListener extends DescriptorEventAdapter implements DescriptorCustomizer {
...
@Override
public void postMerge(DescriptorEvent event) {
    if (event.getChangeSet() != null) {
    ...
    }
}
```

}

This works for a Document list, changeSet is not empty,
but not for ConsumptionRoomAndPost. The changeSet is empty.

Of course I can add own listener ConsumptionRoomAndPostAuditListener for ConsumptionRoomAndPost but for a audit i need a client information and than I have a problem to provide this client information to a ConsumptionRoomAndPostAuditListener.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

After changing relationships to bidirectional, eclipse link tracks changes for all attributes.
I have added to entity ConsumptionRoomAndPost:

```
public class ConsumptionRoomAndPost {
...
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "consumptionRoomAndPost", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Client client;
...
}
```

its all.